# How to create a model with custom loss function with conditionals and using output of the loss to update another variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I'm trying to solve a time series forecasting problem using Tensorflow and I want to implement a custom loss function to optimize model. Problem is forecasting book sales volume for over a year. I want to create a loss function such that it compares `y_pred` with `y_true` but with different penalties for undershoot and overshoot. There is also an assumed inventory as `storage` and its value should update according to the output of loss for each iteration.

What I need to know actually is how to use value of an non-trainable variable as input to the loss function and how to use output of loss function to increase or decrease the value of same variable.

So far I have thought of something like this as the loss function.

```
def loss_function(storage):
  if storage == 0:
    def cost_loss(y_true, y_pred):
      if y_pred <= y_true:
        cost = 20*(y_true - y_pred)
        to_storage = 0
      elif y_pred > y_true:
        cost = 200/30
        to_storage = y_pred - y_true
      return cost, to_storage
  elif storage > 0:
    def cost_loss(y_true, y_pred):
      if y_pred <= y_true:
        if (y_true - y_pred) < storage:
          cost = 200/30
          to_storage = y_pred - y_true
        elif (y_true - y_pred) > storage:
          cost = 20*(y_true - y_pred - storage) + 200/30
          to_storage = y_pred - y_true
      elif y_pred > y_true:
        cost = 200/30
        to_storage = y_pred - y_true
      return cost, to_storage
  return cost_loss
```

and I think the model should contain something like this:

```
storage = tf.Variable(initial_value=0, trainable=False)
cost, to_storage = wrapper(storage)
storage += to_storage
```

Should I create a Model subclass to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**

With some tinkering I have managed to progress a little by using custom training loop:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
epochs = 2
storage = 0
cumulative_cost = 0
for epoch in range(epochs):

  for step in range(len(lstm_train_features)):

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
      step_features = np.reshape(lstm_train_features[step], (1, lstm_train_features.shape[1], lstm_train_features.shape[2]))
      logits = custom_lstm_model(step_features, training=True)
      cost_loss_fn = loss_function(storage)
      loss_value, to_storage = cost_loss_fn(lstm_train_targets[step], logits)
      cumulative_cost += loss_value
      storage += to_storage

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss_value, custom_lstm_model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, custom_lstm_model.trainable_weights))

    if step % 100 == 0:
      print(f"Epoch: {epoch} - Step: {step} - Cost So Far: {cumulative_cost}")
```

Now it raises this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert the argument `type_value`: 6.666666666666667 to a TensorFlow DType.
```

As @Dr.Snoopy stated, it may be due to the loss function being not differentiable.

Comment: Are you aware that you will not be able to train a model using gradient descent since this loss is not differentiable?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, I have somewhat managed to achieve some progress by creating custom training loop, but now when gradient tries to change model's weights it raises ```TypeError: Cannot convert the argument `type_value`: 6.666666666666667 to a TensorFlow DType.```error. I think it may be related with the loss being not differentiable.